# Add custom header for Checkout pages in Magento (1.8.x)

Tags: magento, layout, themes, block, checkout

I am trying to add a customised header to my Checkout pages, I have figured out removing the header from the page is basically adding a  node in the /layout/checkout.xml file, could anyone explain how to basically a new altered header that only applies to all the Checkout pages.

Current default/layout/checkout.xml

```
 <default>
   <remove name="footer"> <!-- removes the footer from checkout -->
... // all other xml data..
</default>
```

pseudocode for my theme

```
if (a CHECKOUT PAGE) {
  use 'custom checkout header'
else
  use the standard default header.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `local.xml` file add the below code to add a custom header to the checkout page

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="root">
      <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header" template="page/html/your_new_header_file_name.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Now create a `new_header.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/page/html` and add the custom header contents in this file. Now update your new header file name in the above template field.

You can replace `default/default` with `your_package_name/your_theme_name`

Comment: Importantly, I had problems caching, when I accessed another route the block was still there.
To prevent this, add:
`<action method="unsetData">
       <key>cache_lifetime</key>
</action>`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add something like

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('new_header') ?>
```

in your page template files (1column.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml, etc)

Also try changing

```
<reference name="root">
```

to

```
<reference name="head">
```

if it is still not working.