# Replacing header.phtml with new checkout_header.phtml in local.xml

Tags: magento, header, checkout

I've copied the code from this answer but still cant change the header code, I'm only getting the standard header.phtml file.
[Add custom header for Checkout pages in Magento (1.8.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451587/add-custom-header-for-checkout-pages-in-magento-1-8-x)

I cant tell if magento is not reading my local.xml file (I've refreshed all caches etc) or if I'm missing something from the code. I've tried several varations of code from searches (as below) but none are working. I'm trying to do it all in local.xml, without editing other template files.

do i need to tell magento to read my new local.xml file? Should I remove the old header first?

```
    <checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as "header">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html_checkout_header.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `header` reference instead of defining a new block named `header`.  This should update the existing header block by referencing it and applying the change.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <reference name="header">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html_checkout_header.phtml</template></action>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>

</layout>
```

Also trivial, but make sure `page/html_checkout_header.phtml` actually exists inside of the theme's **template** folder you are using.

Comment: thanks Axel, I've tried that code and confirm checkout_header.phtml is in themes template folder but magento is still pulling header.phtml from template folder. I've tried lots of variations of the code, even tried getting 'hello world' onto checkout pages from local.xml but magento just seems to be ignoring local.xml....

Comment: Make sure your local.xml is formatted completely.  I've update my answer with the complete local.xml file I've used and tested.  It works for me.  Also make sure you are using the correct theme settings in the Magento configuration.

Comment: thanks again Axel. my local.xml now has exactly what you've written, new header template in the correct template folder and configuration is correct in magento admin. I've been tweaking stuff for hours now, still wont work... must be something silly... i can modify pages directly in header.phtml but cant create a new template only read by checkout_onepage_index..

Comment: Try putting `html_checkout_header.phtml` into the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/` folder and see if the template loads.  If not, move `local.xml` into the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` folder.  If this works, then your theme configuration in the Magento admin is not correct.

Comment: problem solved. I'd installed from magento connect a fix to bypass the first page of the checkout process whether customers register or not and that had been messing with the header. once I disabled that, it works fine. thanks for your help Axel, much appreciated!